# How to read NIFI process metric?

Tags: apache-nifi

Can some please explain the Task\time metric that is part of the NIFI process.
The interval is 5 minutes,as I understand (maybe I'm wrong)

- Process has generated 277,567 flow file in the last 5 minutes
- 34,924 tasks were running in the last 5 min
- What is the 4 hours ???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be found here : https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#processor_anatomy

In shorts, it's the "amount of time taken to perform those tasks" (so within 5 min).